# NullPointerException:tempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable

Tags: react-native

Can I know the what is this error and a solution for this? This error occurred at react native apps randomly, in both debug mode and APKs. reproducing this error is difficult.

I saw this issue in github github-https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17530.

but the solution is not a proper one. Is there a proper solution for this error.

Comment: There are a few different workarounds mentioned in that thread, including this one, which appears to be working for pretty much everyone: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17530#issuecomment-416367184
what have you tried? it looks like the basic issue is a misuse of jsx markup

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned in the github which is adding  <item name="android:editTextBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> line to android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml this file. but it changed UI design to transparent underline of Text-input s. There should be a colored Text input underlines in my app. So I couldn't able to solve my problem with that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It occurs randomly. Just uninstall the app from mobile and restart the server by resetting the cache.

Answer (score 10):

Try to run below command. This worked for me.

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 7):

Just close the app and open it again the problem will be solved. But if anyone knows a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can try both and either of the points, whichever works for  your app:

1. Delete the cache data of your app and let it reload
2. Restart the server using npm start --reset-cache

Answer (score 2):

Add the flowing line of code into `/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:editTextBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       ...
</style>
```

Hope this will work. Happy coding.....

Comment: I will try it on my next release, If its will work you are awesome 

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was resolved so I closed **npm** and then executed the:

```
`react-native run-android.`
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29452/files
Hope this works.
This error arrives due to multiple rerendering of textInput(s).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. close the app
2. restart the server using `npm start --reset-cache`
3. `npm run android`

(didn't need to uninstall the app)

Answer (score 1):

To all of you who are using Expo Go. Just restart the parent Expo Go launcher app on your phone. It works for me. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Guys restarting the packager and clearing cache worked for me!**

Answer (score 0):

If, you are using ExpoGo, try clearing the cache of the ExpoGo launcher app either manually or with the command

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the flowing line of code into /android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item> -->
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```